# Report Generation in Visual Basic 6: when the report is generated I only see the name of the first student in the record in the report

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6, report, adodb

I am working on an automation system in VB, and the project is in it's final stage.
I am working on report generation.The problem I am facing is, I want to create a full year report based on Class of students. How ever when the report is generated I only see the name of the first student in the record in the report or the last if I use a loop.

Just for information, I am using ADODB with Access Database, and Using ADODB.RecordSet to read data.

My Report generation part looks like as follows :

```
Set RS1 = New ADODB.recordSet
    RS1.Open "SELECT * FROM RECORDS WHERE sClass = '" & ClassBox.Text & "';", connection, 3, adLockOptimistic
    If Not RS1.EOF Then
        Set DataReport2.DataSource = RS1.DataSource
    End If
    RS1.MoveFirst

    Do Until RS1.EOF
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("NameLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!sName)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("SectionLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!sSection)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("ClassLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!sClass)

    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("JanLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!January)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("FebLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!February)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("MarLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!March)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("AprLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!April)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("MayLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!May)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("JunLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!June)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("JulLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!July)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("AugLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!August)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("SepLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!September)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("OctLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!October)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("NovLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!November)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("DecLbl").Caption = CStr(RS1!December)
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("TotalLbl").Caption = CStr(Val(RS1!January) + Val(RS1!February) + _
    Val(RS1!March) + Val(RS1!April) + Val(RS1!May) + Val(RS1!June) + Val(RS1!July) + Val(RS1!August) + _
    Val(RS1!September) + Val(RS1!October) + Val(RS1!November) + Val(RS1!December))
    RS1.MoveNext
    Loop
    DataReport2.Show
```

What I want is to create the reports, where the report contains the names and details of the students sequentially based on my search criteria which is this case is class.

Comment: I don't know what DataReport2 is, but you need to bind fields in the report to fields in the RS1. The report will take care of reading the data in. You are just setting the text of the report controls and overwriting the value on each iteration.

Comment: DataReport2 is a report generation tool that comes with Vb-6. I know that the fields are getting over-written, and that's precisely where I have the question. What to do to make the 'Binding' as the data will be shown on the basis of 'Filtering' and not 'As Is' in the table.

Comment: In the report designer put a textbox in the details section and set it's `DataField` property to the name of the field in the recordset. Repeat for each field you want to show. The 'Filtering' will be handled by your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying your existing code. If your controls have a `DataField` (it will depend on the control used), you can try setting that instead of the `Caption` property. I also modified your query to add a SUM(January, ...) field. I believe you could also add a formula field in in the report to do this if you prefer that method. I only added the line continuation so the query didn't scroll forever to the right.

```
Set RS1 = New ADODB.recordSet
RS1.Open "SELECT sName, sSection, sClass, January, February, March, April, " _
    & "May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December, " _
    & "(January + February + March + April + May + " _
    & "June + July + August + September + October + " _
    & "November + December) AS MonthTotal FROM RECORDS " _
    & "WHERE sClass = '" & ClassBox.Text & "'", connection, 3, adLockOptimistic

' RS1.MoveFirst - not needed

DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("NameLbl").DataField = "sName"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("SectionLbl").DataField = "sSection"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("ClassLbl").DataField = "sClass"

DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("JanLbl").DataField= "January"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("FebLbl").DataField = "February"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("MarLbl").DataField = "March"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("AprLbl").DataField = "April"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("MayLbl").DataField = "May"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("JunLbl").DataField = "June"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("JulLbl").DataField = "July"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("AugLbl").DataField = "August"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("SepLbl").DataField = "September"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("OctLbl").DataField = "October"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("NovLbl").DataField = "November"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("DecLbl").DataField = "December"
DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls("TotalLbl").DataField = "MonthTotal"
If Not RS1.EOF Then
    Set DataReport2.DataSource = RS1
    DataReport2.Show
End If
```

Comment: The query part is giving problem and is being marked in RED. i.e RS.Open "" part

Comment: There is problem with your query!

Comment: @Priyabrata I've update the query again. Your OP was a problem with how to bind the recorset to the report. If my query is causing errors that you can't correct please at least post what error you are getting.

Comment: I added a screen-shot in your post. Isn't that being shown ??

Comment: Current error : "Object doesn't support this property or method (Error-438)

Comment: @Priyabrata Error on which line? What type are the controls on the report? I checked and RptLabels do not have a DataField property. You must have RptTextBoxes on the report. Have you tried opening the report and binding the report fields by assigning the recordset field names to the DataField property?

Comment: I did and it runs, but the problem remains same as in the Parent question @jac

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41352/discussion-between-jac-and-priyabrata)